# winforms generates an error when i load a folder with no image

Tags: c#, picturebox

I made a slideshow program. When I load a folder with images inside, it's working fine. BUt when I load a folder with no images inside, it generates an error. What might be the problem?

Here's my code.

```
private void openSlideShowFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string[] pics1 = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.jpg");
        string[] pics2 = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.jpeg");
        string[] pics3 = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.bmp");
        folderFile = new string[pics1.Length + pics2.Length + pics3.Length];
        Array.Copy(pics1, 0, folderFile, 0, pics1.Length);
        Array.Copy(pics2, 0, folderFile, pics1.Length, pics2.Length);
        Array.Copy(pics3, 0, folderFile, pics1.Length + pics2.Length, pics3.Length);
        selected = 0;
        showImage(folderFile[selected]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What might be the error be? Error message please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have no files, then `folderFile.Length == 0` and this `showImage(folderFile[selected]);` will throw an exception, because there is no elements in array at all and at 0 index too. It is an access outside of the array bounds. You should check array bounds:

```
if (folderFile.Length > 0)
    showImage(folderFile[selected]);
```